# D3 data binding with slider and play/pause

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, d3.js, slider

I am looking to implement a map with a 'play/pause' feature that will overlay items as the time scale progresses. However, I also wanted to give users the ability to set the time themselves. Very similar to

[Mike's work here](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/09/25/sports/americas-cup-course.html?_r=0)

Any ideas on the best way to implement this? I would like to avoid html element sliders because of a lack of styling options (as far as filling up the bar with different colors, it gets messy overlaying SVG). There is also d3.slider (independent open source on git), but the documentation is lacking. Is using a brush handler the best option?

Thank you!

Comment: Google for brush slider or d3 svg slider. https://gist.github.com/mbostock/6452972